# How do I install antlr4 for Python3 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, antlr4, miniconda

I'm trying to install antlr4 for Python 3 on Windows. I run the following `pip` command successfully:

`pip install antlr4-python3-runtime`

Installs the packages, no problem. I'm using the Miniconda environment, and the files are where they are expected.

When I try to run `antlr4` from the command line, though, error is returned:

`'antlr4' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I've verified that my path variables are as expected... and I run other packages installed via pip in the Miniconda environment with no issue. I've also tried installing to the main Python installation on Windows via CMD, and it installs without issue... but same response when I try to run. I also tried to do this on my Mac, same issue.

I'm assuming there is an issue with the antlr4 build, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything before moving on.

***Update 0***
@Bart's answer is the way to go, but now I'm having trouble running the .jar file. It's throwing an error that says that my Java is out of date (that I' mon class file version 52 and it requires 55). But I have Java 1.8, which should be higher than that. Here is the error below:

```
C:\Users\mathg>java -jar C:\Users\mathg\miniconda3\Scripts\antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar -help
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/antlr/v4/Tool has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

***Update 1***
I've done some more digging around, and followed the installation instructions here: [antlr4: Getting Started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md). Updated all the environment variables, created the .bat files as required, and I ran again... but even though it's on my PATH now, still same error. There may be something wonky with my Java install, but I did do a clean reinstall. I did find a similar issue on the GitHub here, but seems to be resolved. [Related antlr4 GitHub issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3744)

***Update 2***
The answer to my issue with running the antlr4 .jar file was to reinstall an earlier version of Java. That completely fixed it. If anyone else is going down this rabbit hole, take a look at the GitHub issue link I posted.

Comment: Do you have the antlr runtime set up properly? Look at https://antlr.org in the Quick Start, in the 3rd section (three buttons on the lower right).

Comment: Is that necessary for the Python version though? Documentation says it's not as everything works from source when using Python

Comment: Look in your Python `Scripts` folders to see if there's an executable called `antlr4.bat`. If you can find it, make sure the folder is in your PATH.

Comment: antlr4.bat is missing. And in fact that's what made believe at first that the pip installation is corrupted. There is a pygrun.py file which is command line runnable, but it does not take the same arguments as antlr4 should.

Comment: If it's the case that the command line interface is broken in the current build, is it possible for me just to import antlr4 directly in a python script and build my files there?

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-tools and dispense with aliases, manually downloading the antlr4 .jar file, manually installing java, adjusting the PATH variable, adding JAVA_HOME variable, manually running `java -jar ....complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 *.g4`, etc, etc, etc. You only need to set up Python3 and Pip, run `pip install antlr4-tools`, then you can just do `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 *.g4` and not worry about the right version of Java to run the tool. The "antlr4" command-line tool with download everything.

Comment: Thanks @kaby76! I have to say that this has been a confusing road for me :) seems to conflict with the answer given below, but I am for sure going to try that because if there's anything I have discovered in this process, it's that I don't like messing with Java and I don't fully understand its versioning system, and I just wish I could stay in my nice little Python / C family snow globe forever 

Comment: @kaby76 -- pip install antlr4-tools totally did not work for me.  The pip install command ran fine; but when I tried to actually run antlr4, it complained about not finding java, and a registry key value being improperly set, and back to the rabbit hole we go.

Comment: @LionKimbro It sounds like you have remnants of java installed. Remove any java installed in settings/apps, verify that java.exe does not exist at a command-line prompt, remove JAVA_HOME and traces of a java directory in PATH, and do a find across your file systems for java.exe and remove along with associated files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`antlr4` is not a binary shipped with `antlr4-python3-runtime`. It is just an alias for the command:

```
java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar
```

In other words, when you want to generate a parser from your `.g4` grammar file, you need to download the `antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar` file and have a Java runtime installed. You only need Java to generate the parser classes, after which you need the Python runtime classes to use these generated parser classes.

For example, you have a grammar called `MyLanguage.g4`:

```
grammar MyLanguage;

parse
 : GREET NAME EOF
 ;

GREET : 'Hi' | 'Hello';
NAME  : [a-zA-Z]+;
SPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Then this is what you'll have to do:

1. generate parser classes:

```
java -jar antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar MyLanguage.g4 -Dlanguage=Python3
```

which will generate `MyLanguageLexer.py`, `MyLanguageParser.py` (and some listener classes).

2. use the lexer and parser:

```py
from antlr4 import *
from MyLanguageLexer import MyLanguageLexer
from MyLanguageParser import MyLanguageParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexer = MyLanguageLexer(InputStream('Hi Trekkie'))
    parser = MyLanguageParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    parse_tree = parser.parse()
    print(parse_tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

The script above only needs the library you installed with `antlr4-python3-runtime` (and are importing with `from antlr4 import *`). If you runt this script, the following will be printed:

```
(parse Hi Trekkie <EOF>)
```

Comment: So I do have the .jar file. Can you point me to some documentation that shows me exactly what I need to do with it? I see the documentation on how to install it, but I'm not quite sure how that interacts with the Python installation

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you mean, so I should install the Java runtime, but the Java runtime will look for the python installation when I call it to make a python file?

Comment: @Trekkie not quite. The Java runtime just generates the lexer and parser Python source files. And to use the lexer and parser in your Python code, you need the antlr4-python3-runtime. I added a quick example to get started.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you! I can work with this!

Comment: Yeah that was a concept I was completely missing because as it's explained on the ANTLR mega tutorial that is very popular, it's literally just pip install and then run it from command line and point it to your.g file. Maybe this subtlety was explained in the multiple documents that I've been reading, but I just went right over it

Comment: I'm still having trouble starting the jar file. See my update to the question above if you have time? Basically I have the most up to date Java... 1.8... but the error I'm getting says that my version is too old. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Java, no dice. Still getting that weird error.

Comment: (Going to un-accept the answer in the hopes that it becomes active again)

Comment: Figured out the issue was that antlr4 apparently doesn't work with the latest version of Java (see my edit). For all intents and purposes, though, your answer good to go. :) Accepted again, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

"this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"
the error message above means your java version is java 8 or java 1.8, not java 18 or called java eighteen, they are two different version

Comment: Yeah maybe I had some unholy combination of the two on my system installed. In any event, uninstalling and reinstalling latest Java didn't fix it. I had to install the Java from 2018 to get it to work. Also Java versioning is confusing AF